# How to make a for loop in pymongo/python with collections?

Tags: python, pymongo

How to make a loop iterating over all collections in pymongo?

I have this code:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list_courses):
    bulk_demographics = "db." + item + ".demographics"

    for i in bulk_demographics.find({"user_id":1}).limit(1):
        print i
```

"list_courses" contains all the different collection names in my mongo database.

**It seems that the error comes from the concat action**, because it works perfectly when I paste the name of the collection directly.

This is the error that I get:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-cb93513f793d> in <module>()
      1 for index, item in enumerate(list_courses):
      2     bulk_demographics = "db." + item + ".demographics"
----> 3     for i in bulk_demographics.find({"user_id":1}).limit(1):
      4         print i
```

TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, dict found

Comment: `"db." + item + ".demographics"` is building a string. You seem to be building a string that looks like the code you want to run, and hoping it will behave like that code. That's pretty much never the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyMongo [documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#getting-a-collection) indicates that if you want to access a collection from a PyMongo database using a string that represents its name, you use bracket notation instead of dot notation:

```
bulk_demographics = db[item].demographics
```

Comment: Awesome! That worked. Thank you!

This is finally my code:
    for index, item in enumerate(list_courses):
    
    cursor1 = db[item].demographics.find({}).limit(1)
    for i in cursor1:
        print i